# Case sensitive in Cloudera Impala table column name

Tags: cloudera, impala

I have installed Coludera VM. Tried to fetch data from Impala database using query editor. If I give upper case column name in query, always getting column name in lower case. Is there any limitations for column name as like we should use column name in lower case?

Sample Query: 
  select orderid as **COLUMN1** from default.orders

Result:

column1

10248 
10249 
10278

Answer (score 1):

From the [Impala documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_identifiers.html):

> Impala identifiers are always case-insensitive. That is, tables named
>   t1 and T1 always refer to the same table, regardless of quote
>   characters. Internally, Impala always folds all specified table and
>   column names to lowercase. This is why the column headers in query
>   output are always displayed in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try these table properties when creating the table. Make sure to put in your column names and types.

```
tblproperties (
'avro.schema.literal'='
{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"SchemaName",
    "fields":[
        {"name":"COLUMN1","type":["null","long"]},
        {"name":"COLUMN2","type":["null","string"]}
    ]
}'
)
```

Inspired by https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe#AvroSerDe-Useschema.literalandembedtheschemainthecreatestatement